# Benefits of using sqlclient data provider with sql server 2005 over oledb data provider

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ado.net, oledb, sqlclient

Recently I think of shifting from oledb data provider to sqlclient as I am using sql server 2005 express edition as my app's backend which contain millions of records..

Can anybody give me concrete reasons for the same

please reply sooon

Answer (score 2):

As your using sql server 2005 as your app backend i would expect performance to be better with sqlclient as there will be no sort of transalation layer , due to it communicating via the Tabular Data Stream (TDS) which you wouldn't get with oledb due to it being a generic provider.

It mentions it in the MSDN link below...

> System.Data.SqlClient includes a tabular data stream (TDS) parser to communicate directly with SQL Server.

[MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb9s9ks0.aspx)

Another link which mentions the TDS

[ADO.NET and SQL Server Performance Tips](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/tips/ado_net_performance_p1.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Dupe? [What are the pros and cons of OleDB versus SQLClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473932/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-oledb-versus-sqlclient)