# How to get rid of this error: An OLE DB Provider was not specified in the ConnectionString. An example would be, 'Provider=SQLOLEDB;'

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

The purpose of my application is when a user types in a customer, their username and a message into the respective textboxes, it's supposed to be recorded into a table on SQL Server after the user presses the send button.

Here's my code:

```
Public Class Form1

Dim Con As OleDbConnection
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand

Dim conString As String = "Data Source=176.111.555.24;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;User ID=Username;Password=Password"

Public Sub MessageSent()

    Try

        Dim con As New OleDbConnection
        con.ConnectionString = conString
        con.Open()

        cmd.Connection = con

        cmd.CommandText = "insert into tblmessage(Customer, UserName, Message) values('" & txtCustomer.Text & "', '" & txtUserName.Text & "', '" & rtfMessage.Text & "')"


        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        con.Close()
        MsgBox("Message Sent")

        con.Close()
        con.Dispose()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)

    End Try

End Sub

   Private Sub btnSend_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSend.Click
        MessageSent()
    End Sub
```

I'm getting the following error:

> An OLE DB Provider was not specified in the ConnectionString.  An example would be, 'Provider=SQLOLEDB;'.

What is it that I'm doing wrong and how can this be resolved.

Comment: If the DB is SQL Server why are you using OleDB?

Comment: How would you re-write this?

Comment: Okay. Sorry! I'll do better next time!!

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are trying to give a SQL Server connection string to an `OleDbConnection`.  You need to either use a `SqlConnection` to open with that connection string or else you need to create a valid OLEDB connection string to point to that database.  For reference, see [this site](https://www.connectionstrings.com).

Comment: Dim conString As String = "Data Source=176.111.555.24;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;User ID=Username;Password=Password"

Comment: I want to use something like this:

Dim con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conStr").ConnectionString)

Comment: Probably best to ask that as another separate question, but you'll need to explain what, specifically, about doing it that way isn't working for you.  On the face of it, that doesn't look wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are just missing this bit: `Provider=SQLOLEDB;`

For example:

```
Dim conString As String = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=176.111.555.24;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;User ID=Username;Password=Password"
```

Answer (score 2):

When you want to connect to an MS SQL database you should use [SQL connection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of OleDbConnection.

The same is true for [sqlCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand(v=vs.110).aspx) over the OldDbommand.

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473932/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-oledb-versus-sqlclient) as some answers explaining the difference between Sql and OldDb Client.

```
Public Sub MessageSent()

  Try
    Using con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection


      con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=176.111.555.24;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;User ID=Username;Password=Password"
      con.Open()

      Using cmd As New SqlCommand
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into tblmessage(Customer, UserName, Message) values('" & txtCustomer.Text & "', '" & txtUserName.Text & "', '" & rtfMessage.Text & "')"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
      End Using

      MsgBox("Message Sent")
      con.Close()           


    End Using


  Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
  End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of declaring these globally:

Dim Con As SqlConnection
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand

Can I put them into my subroutine?

Comment: I didn't change it in the example but yes, you should always try to avoid using global instance if you don't have to.

Comment: It's also a good practice to wrap the sqlConnection / sqlCommand inside a [using statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) to make you they are disposed correctly.

Comment: I updated the code to show you how to work with the using statement (and without a global instance).

Comment: Good, but slightly better would be `MsgBox(ex.ToString())`.